# Can I use T4 programmatically from C#?

Tags: c#, t4, template-engine

I am writing software that produces C# code. Mostly I am using [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) and StringBuilder.

Is there any way to use T4 templates direct from my code?

Comment: Are you trying to automate T4 from C#

Comment: Exactly. I have WinForms application, in which user creates service and then application needs to generate c# (c,java...) code.

Answer (score 11):

[Oleg Sych](http://www.olegsych.com/) describes how to do this here: [Understanding T4: Preprocessed Text Templates](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203080603/http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/). Note that it looks like you'll need Visual Studio 2010 to generate a preprocessed Text Template, but you'll be able to host the preprocessed Text Template wherever you like - including within your WinForms application.

Comment: The second link is now dead.

Comment: Pointed second link to corresponding page on archive.org. HTH

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

// Set text transform program (this could change according to the Windows version)
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\TextTemplating\\10.0\\TextTransform.exe";

// Specify T4 template file
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\template.tt";

proc.Start();
```

Comment: Do not assume that C:\ exists.  Especially do not assume that TextTemplating is installed.